# How To Insert Value In textarea using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to insert value in `textarea` field using Excel automation, I have done a lot of research but don't get success.

I have used the scripts bellow.

```vb
IE.document.all("content").Item.Value = "Hi"
IE.document.all("content").Value = "Hi"
IE.document.all("content").innerHtml = "Hi"
```

None of the examples work.

Comment: .innertext ? i'll have a look

Comment: Why are you using `document.all`? This is deprecated and may not work on the site. Also, is your selector `"content"` a class name? If so, you might be looking for something like `IE.document.querySelector(".content").innerHTML = "Hi"`. Add your HTML for a better reference though.

Comment: Could you please provide the related html code so that we can have a test to see how to locate the element? Besides, I agree with Robert, you should use other css selector instead of `document.all`, it's been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/all).

Comment: Sounds good, I'll put the comment into an answer then so this question can be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

### Don't use Document.all

As per [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/all) `document.all` is deprecated since HTML5 and may not work with your site.

> This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible;. . .

### Selectors you can use

Really, the selectors that are good to use would be [`.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), [`.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), and [`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/querySelectorAll).

### Solution using correct selector

I prefer to stick with `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`.

Using your example, it appears you are attempting to grab the only `textarea` with a class of content, something like `<textarea class="content"></textarea>`.

Therefore, that example would look like

```vb
IE.document.querySelector(".content").innerHTML = "Hi"
```

Comment: thanks, it's working. how can I click on this type class >  class="btn btn-success" there is a two-class how to click on

Comment: Great, if this answers your question then please mark it as answered. Chances are you will need to use something more than just the class in that instance as `btn btn-sucess` is probably some framework like bootstrap where the classes are reused all over the place. With that said, if this is the only element then it would be something like `document.querySelector(".btn.btn-success").Click`

Comment: Here is a list of basic css selectors that might help you from [W3Shools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). If you have more follow up questions, then it's best to make those new question within SO. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. Check if it's work or not.
IE.document.all("content").Text= "Hi"

Or
Try to to add text properties at the end of the code